# Inkscape: A proper way to align arrows heads with a given curve

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve, arrow

I have an arrow and a given curve as shown below:

[image]

I want to duplicate the arrow and align it as follows:

[image]

Unfortunately, I've done that manually. It 's not perfect and is very tedious if I have many curves.

I wonder if there is a proper way in Inkscape to achieve that.

I appreciate any help

**EDIT**: 
I have tried using Align but it didn't work, here is the result:

[image]

Comment: align it to the curve edge not curve center

Comment: @joojaa: I tried to use *Align* but it didn't work. I will edit tthe post to add that

Comment: I don't know about Inkscape, but in Illustrator you could probably let the horizontal lines overlap the curve, divide/cut them using the curve and then delete part you don't need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one approach, there may be others.

1. Draw two straight lines, select them both, then create a bunch of lines in between using *Extensions > Generate from Path > Interpolate*, ungroup them, then do *Path > Combine*
2. Draw the curve

[image]

3. Copy the curved path (you'll need this later)
4. Select All <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then do *Path > Cut Path* or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
5. Select and Delete the pieces that were overlapped by the curved shape

[image]

6. Add the arrow markers to the paths
7. Paste in place <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - this will paste the curved path you previously copied in step 3, which was consumed in the Cut Path operation
8. Select the curved path, and nudge it to the right using the arrow keys until it is in position

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried the cut but it didn't cut. I tried to convert them to a path but it didn't work too.

Comment: @Thiziriyoor It does work, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to do it!  You may not be able to see the cut, but it's there. Also make sure you did the path combine part of step 1

Comment: Yes it works. But I don't have to convert the curve to a path otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Thiziriyoor There is nowhere in the steps where I said convert the curve to a path.

Comment: Yes you are right. Just because I started with a curve that I've converted to a path. Your answer works perfectly. However I couldn't get it to work when I use a parameteric curve (I know this is not mentioned in my question). Is there a way around that? or do I have to ask another question? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103172/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-thiziri-yoor).